# Issue with MySQL Concat and like command

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to validate the data in `MYSQL` table. Table has 4 fields :

- Firstname
- Middlename
- Lastname
- Fullname

  I want to compare if `CONCAT(firstname, ' ',  LASTNAME)`, matches `Fullname`

Here is the command I am using :

```
select * from  user_info where CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) 
like  CONCAT('%', fullname, '%')
```

However, this is not working. But the following command works :

```
select * from  user_info where CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) 
like  '%JOHN DOE%'
```

What could be the issue with the `MySQL` command ?

[image]

Comment: We're going to need to see some table data here to make complete sense of your observations.

Comment: What about the middle name, which is presumably part of the full name field?  Obviously your query won't work because you don't take into account the middle name (if it exists).

Comment: Hello Tim, Middlename is often empty in most of the cases ( including in fullname field)

Comment: You need to show us data to make your question reproducible.  Otherwise, we can only speculate as to what the problem is.

Comment: Just attached the screenshot of the data. I compare firstname middlename with fullname and is not working ( Same goes with firstname and lastname compared with fullname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change order of condition in your code :-

```
select * from  table1 where fullname
like  CONCAT('%', trim(CONCAT(firstname,' ',middlename,' ',lastname)) , '%')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5f38f/8)

Comment: That is not the case Gaurav, The screenshot attached is partial. Middlename (& Lastname) is not always empty. I tried 2 queries concatanating firstname & middlename and firstname & lastname seperately.

Comment: @Kiran:- Updated my answer, please check now.

Comment: @Gauvrav, it really worked. Thanks a lot. But I fail to understand the logic behind it. Would you please elaborate on your answer. It might help others who might be facing the same issue as well.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the presence/absence of the middle name.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:-  I just modified the code which OP provided. Added middlename also.

Comment: @Kiran:- Let's understand it with an example, I am considering first record of data you posted. The code which you were using earlier would try to do :-   WHERE DEEPAK LIKE '%DEEPAK BANSAL%', which will never satisfy, but if you reverse order it will be:- WHERE DEEPAK BANSAL LIKE '%DEEPAK%', which satisfies the condition. If it  resolves your problem please accept as solution.

Comment: @Kiran:- Add trim also in code, it will eliminate spaces. I have modified answer with same.

Answer (score 2):

Your newly attached data confirms what I suspected, namely that the full name is not necessarily composes simply of the first and last name, but include the middle name, or might even be missing any of the three components.  One option here would be to assert that each component present does appear somewhere inside the full name, in the correct order, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    fullname REGEXP
    CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN firstname IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT('[[:<:]]', COALESCE(firstname, ''), '[[:>:]]')
             ELSE '' END,
        '.*',
        CASE WHEN middlename IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT('[[:<:]]', COALESCE(middlename, ''), '[[:>:]]')
             ELSE '' END,
        '.*',
        CASE WHEN lastname IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONCAT('[[:<:]]', COALESCE(lastname, ''), '[[:>:]]')
             ELSE '' END);
```

### Demo

Comment: Why bother with the coalesce when you have already asserted that the value is not null?

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. Really appreciate your time. As Nick suggested, the fields are not NULL though. It really worked.

Comment: @Kiran Reload your page, I changed my answer.  I had to think about this for a while, because your question/data did not make it entirely clear what you are trying to do here.